# Failed to destroy the filter named [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter]

Tags: java, spring-boot

while running spring boot application am getting below error

```
SEVERE: Failed to destroy the filter named [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter] of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4598)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5425)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:496)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:149)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at com.rsvps.ProcessingApplication.main(ProcessingApplication.java:26)
```

And here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.rsvps</groupId>
   <artifactId>SparkStructuredStreaming</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>SparkStructuredStreaming</name>
   <description>Read from Kafka via Structured Streaming and output the results to console</description>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
         <version>2.11.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
       <exclusions>  
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>protobuf-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.google.protobuf</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>           
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
<!--       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.1</version>
      </dependency> -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>   
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>protobuf-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.google.protobuf</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion> 
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>  
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>  
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>   
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>                                 
      </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.2</version>   
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </exclusion>  
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>                      
      </exclusions>              
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.2</version> 
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
            <configuration>
               <scalaCompatVersion>2.11</scalaCompatVersion>
               <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
            <!-- other settings-->
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>compile</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

can anyone please suggest what's wrong happening ? Do I need to exlude any dependency ? Not able to understand why its happening.

I'm stuck in this issue from last 2 days. Its a spark structred streaming spring boot application.

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Update

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.rsvps</groupId>
   <artifactId>SparkStructuredStreaming</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>SparkStructuredStreaming</name>
   <description>Read from Kafka via Structured Streaming and output the results to console</description>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
         <version>2.11.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
       <exclusions>  
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>protobuf-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.google.protobuf</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>           
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>   
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>protobuf-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.google.protobuf</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion> 
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>  
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>  
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>   
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>                                 
      </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.2</version>   
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </exclusion>  
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>                      
      </exclusions>              
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.2</version> 
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>         
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.15.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
            <configuration>
               <scalaCompatVersion>2.11</scalaCompatVersion>
               <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
            <!-- other settings-->
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>compile</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions of frameworks. You are mixing different apache spark and Spring Boot versions. That is going to be problematic at some point.

Comment: @M.Deinum, what you'll suggest to fix it ?

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions (as mentioned).

Comment: @M.Deinum, updated pom and now all starters having same versions...still causing issue

Comment: looks like something is pulling in a newer servlet API version or something.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error and I was not able to identify the actual problem.
For me some of the VM-arguments were missing in my Run/Debug configurations. so after adding missing arguments in the VM option, I was able to build the application.

so if you are getting the same error, try to check the VM-arguments you are using is correct.